# Pass varible in syscalls in C

Tags: c, linux, variables, operating-system, hook

I'm trying to make a custom system call for my OS course following these instructions from the link bellow:
https://uwnthesis.wordpress.com/2016/12/26/basics-of-making-a-rootkit-from-syscall-to-hook/

My kernel's version is 5.3.9.
 This is my code so far:
 My .c file (located in /usr/srclinux-5.3.9):

```
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/tty.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include "pname.h"
asmlinkage long sys_process_name(char* process_name){
    /*placeholder to print full string to tty*/
    char name[32];
    strcpy(name, process_name);

    /*tasklist struct to use*/
    struct task_struct *task;

    /*tty struct*/
    struct tty_struct *my_tty;

    /*get current tty*/
    my_tty = get_current_tty();

    /*<sched.h> library method that iterates through list of processes from task_struct defined above*/
    for_each_process(task){
        printk("Task name: %s.\n",task->comm);
        printk("Task ID: %ld.\n",task->pid);
        printk("Task for compare: %s.\n", name);
        printk("\n");
        /*compares the current process name (defined in task->comm) to the passed in name*/
        if(strcmp(task->comm, name) == 0){
        printk("Process Found!\n");
        /*convert to string and put into name[]*/
        sprintf(name, "PID = %ld\n", (long)task_pid_nr(task));
        /*show result to user that called the syscall*/
        (my_tty->driver->ops->write) (my_tty, name, strlen(name)+1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My .h file:

```
asmlinkage long sys_process_name(char*process_name);
```

My Makefile:

```
obj-y := pname.o
```

I have included this system call to my syscalls_64.tbl and syscalls.h.

After successfully compiled the code above I tried this code to test the syscall testPname.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char name[32];
puts("Enter process to find");
scanf("%s",name);
strtok(name, "\n");
long int status = syscall(335, name); //syscall number 335 and passing in the string.}
printf("System call returned %ld\n", status);
return 0;
}
```

But when I put a bunch of printk into the pname.c file and notice that "char* process_name" was never pass from my testPname to the syscall, so the strcmp was never reached. I've tried browsing for a way to pass the parameter to the system call but haven't been able to get there.